# Angular input type="date" displaying incorrect value, timezone issue

Tags: javascript, angular

I'm storing date in DB as UTC format:

```
this.eventItem.date: "2023-06-21T00:00:00.000Z"
```

The input form field value is displaying '2023-06-20' (number day is incorrect), I think it's a timezone issue. I'm in a region +3, how can i solve this? Thanks in advance.

```
console.log(new Date(this.eventItem.date));
```

logs:

`'Tue Jun 20 2023 21:00:00 GMT-0300 (hora estándar de Argentina)'`

```js
initializeForm(): void {
  this.detailsEventForm = this.fb.group({
    isActive: [this.eventItem.isActive],
    date: '2023-06-21',
    shifts: [this.eventItem.shifts]
  });
}
```

```html
<mat-form-field floatLabel="auto" appearance="outline" color="primary">
  <mat-label>Date</mat-label>
  <input
    matInput
    formControlName="date"
    [matDatepicker]="datePickerDate"
    readonly
    (click)="datePickerDate.open()">
  <mat-datepicker-toggle [for]="datePickerDate" matSuffix></mat-datepicker-toggle>
  <mat-datepicker #datePickerDate></mat-datepicker>
</mat-form-field>
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it whis way:

```js
initializeForm(): void {
  const utcDate = new Date(this.eventItem.date);
  const timezoneOffsetMinutes = utcDate.getTimezoneOffset();
  const formattedDate = new Date(utcDate.getTime() + (timezoneOffsetMinutes * 60 * 1000));

  this.detailsEventForm = this.fb.group({
    isActive: [this.eventItem.isActive],
    date: [formattedDate],
    shifts: [this.eventItem.shifts]
  });
}
```